# Animating Loading Logo to Sidebar Corner after Completion in React

Tags: reactjs, animation, css-animations

I've included an animated film with what I want to do. After the loading logo is finished, in my scenario, It want to go to the corner of my sidebar,
[enter link description here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1W7y-V-Ucca4YYy1y5SPhrLTMt_fyA7pj/view?usp=sharing)